# TabLayout: Click on Tab TextView to scroll on top of listview

Tags: android

I have two Fragments within a TabLayout.
Now, I want to add an onclick listener to the tablayout. The fragments contain a listview, each. Is it possible to click on the tablayout and put the listview to the top?
Thanks.

Comment: Please share the code that you have

Comment: are you using TabLayout with ViewPager ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `onTabReslected(Tab tab)` [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener.html#onTabReselected(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.Tab)) and scroll the `ListView` to position 0.

```
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab){

  if(mListView.getAdapter() != null && mListView.getAdapter().getItemCount() > 0)
     mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

}
```